# How to get, resize and display photos from external storage

Tags: dart, flutter

As the question suggests, I've been trying to load, resize and display all photos from local storage on android with Flutter in a `GridView`, which is quite the common feature for many apps working with multimedia. What I did is installing the `path_provider` package and image packages (along with the permissions plugin for android run-time permissions) and tried to get a list of the `Image` (from the 'image' package), so I can resize them correctly for memory efficiency and display with `Image.memory`. However, my app hangs when doing it this way:

```
Future<List<i.Image>> getImages() async {
  bool hasPermission =
      await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(Permission.ReadExternalStorage);
  if (!hasPermission) {
    bool requestedPermission = await SimplePermissions
        .requestPermission(Permission.ReadExternalStorage);
    if (requestedPermission) {
    } else {
      print('Permission Denied');
      return [];
    }
  }
  Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  return directory
      .list(
        recursive: true,
      )
      .where((entity) =>
          entity.existsSync() &&
          (entity.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpg') ||
              entity.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.png') ||
              entity.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpeg')))
      .map<i.Image>((entity) {
    File file = new File(entity.path);
    return i.copyResize(i.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync()), 200);
  }).toList();
}
```

Is there anyone who has already built such a feature in their app or found an issue implementing it this way?

Comment: have you tried to put breakpoints into your flow, to see what happens? It seems to me that you should make this function async instead of doing it synchronous.

Comment: Actually I've tried it async too and still not working, but the problem appeared when using the methods from the image package for resizing and returning it as Image.

Comment: Have you come across a solution yet? Also, looks like we don't have handle to the thumbnails that get created in phone gallery automatically which we simply can use.

Comment: Well @VijayKumarKanta I actually haven't found any solution yet, so I left it to the side for now. But what happens is that if I try to render this in a grid or list of Image.memory() or Image.file() (if I used the list of paths instead), then memory goes crazy, so it's definitely a wrong way to build such a feature. Those photos need to be thumbnailed locally in memory before rendering all of those in a list or grid, but my code didn't work as expected (expected in theory at least, idk what I'm missing here)

Comment: @TsortanidisChristos yes, I had to do similar. I had to dig deep to pull out the jpg and png images full versions, resized them myself, and then saved them as thumbs in my own directory. Such a fuss I had to create. haha..

Comment: @VijayKumarKanta Oh so I can them in temporary directory? But is this actually efficient? What happens on next app session or if a new photo is taken?

Comment: @TsortanidisChristos no I got a handle to external storage using permissions package like you, then used .create() function to create the directory with a name, and pushed my pictures there. Later when I load up, they show up, cuz my app's still in the phone. If it's uninstalled, it's a different story though.